# Email system, send or save button option

Tags: php, email, system

I'm coding a simple e-mail system and having a logical complication regarding saving it to drafts. I've created one file for composing the message.

```
<?php
include ('connection.php');


$sender = $_POST['sender'];
$sendto = $_POST['sendto'];
$title = $_POST['title'];
$body = $_POST['body'];
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$string = strstr($sendto, '@');


    if(!empty($_POST) and ($string != '@raymart.com')) {
    (mysql_query("INSERT INTO sent (sender, sendto, title, body, date) VALUES ('".$sender."', '".$sendto."', '".$title."', '".$body."', '".$date."')") or die(mysql_error())); {
        $message = $body . "\r\n";
        $message .= "Date sent: ". $date;
        mail($sendto,$title,$message,$sender);
        echo 'Email successfully sent!';
        }
    }
    if(!empty($_POST) and ($string == '@raymart.com')) {
    (mysql_query("INSERT INTO sent (sender, sendto, title, body, date) VALUES ('".$sender."', '".$sendto."', '".$title."', '".$body."', '".$date."')") or die(mysql_error()));
    (mysql_query("INSERT INTO inbox (sendto, sender, title, body, date) VALUES ('".$sendto."', '".$sender."', '".$title."', '".$body."', '".$date."')") or die(mysql_error()));
    {
    echo 'Email successfully sent!';
    }
    }

?>
<div class="container">
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post">
<fieldset>

<!-- Form Name -->
<legend>Compose Mail</legend>

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="sender">From: </label>
  <div class="controls">
    <input id="sender" name="sender" placeholder="Your email" class="input-xlarge cmps" type="text">
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="sendto">Send To: </label>
  <div class="controls">
    <input id="sendto" name="sendto" placeholder="Send To" class="input-xlarge cmps" type="text">
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="title">Title: </label>
  <div class="controls">
    <input id="title" name="title" placeholder="Title/Subject" class="input-xlarge cmps" type="text">
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Textarea -->
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="body">Message: </label>
  <div class="controls">                     
    <textarea id="body" name="body" class="cmps"></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
<button type="submit" id="button" class="btn btn-success">Send!</button>
<a href="save.php" class="btn-danger btn">Save to drafts</a>

</fieldset>
</form>
</div>
```

I've also created the action.. which is the "save.php"

```
<?php
include ('connection.php');


$sender = $_POST['sender'];
$sendto = $_POST['sendto'];
$title = $_POST['title'];
$body = $_POST['body'];
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$newURL = "drafts.php";



    mysql_query("INSERT INTO draft (sender, sendto, title, body, date) VALUES ('".$sender."', '".$sendto."', '".$title."', '".$body."', '".$date."')") or die(mysql_error()); 
        $message = $body . "\r\n";
        $message .= "Date sent: ". $date;
        echo 'Email successfully sent!';
        header('Location: '.$newURL);



?>
```

It does add an entry to the draft table but no values. What must be the problem guys? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You are wide-open for SQL injection attacks... and your `<form>` has no `action` attribute, so it will never submit to `save.php`, it'll just be submitting to itself.

Comment: Your script is wide open for SQL Injection. At the very least use mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['sender']) on all the variables that go into your query string.

Comment: With <a> tag you are not submitting the form
Therefore you cannot use $_POST['anything'].

Comment: Thanks for the info and tips guys!! Will update this thread later :) Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Solved this problem by modifying my  tag

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="save.php">
```

Added the action="save.php"

and used mysql_real_escape_string to prevent SQL Injection attacks! :)

Comment: You are using mysql_query() - All the mysql_* functions are deprecated, you should try and learn PDO and use prepared statements (it's not difficult). From the PHP Manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php - "It is recommended to use either the mysqli or PDO_MySQL extensions. It is not recommended to use the old mysql extension for new development, as it has been deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0 and will be removed in the future".